# Regex: Match optional string to group

Tags: regex, vbscript, regex-group, optional-values

I have a file describing objects in which some properties of the object are optional. For example (color is optional):

```
type=dog
sex=male
name=wolf
color=brown
type=dog
sex=male
name=bob
type=cat
sex=male
name=tom
color=black
type=dog
sex=female
name=simona
color=white
```

I'm looking for a regex that gives me a pair of properties for a dog "name" - "color". I'm waiting for something like this:

```
wolf - brown
bob - 
simona - white
```

I started with

```
type=dog[\s\S]*?name=(\w+)[\s\S]*?color=(\w+)
```

Which gives wrong:

```
wolf - brown
bob - black
simona - white
```

Then I made group from color(which gives the same) and added "?" quantifier:

```
type=dog[\s\S]*?name=(\w+)[\s\S]*?(color=(\w+))?
```

But, instead of the desired result I lost 2nd group in all matches:

```
wolf - 
bob - 
simona -
```

What's wrong with my expression and how to achieve my goal. Please do not use Lookbehind, Lookahead and Conditionals. VBScript not implement them.

[My example on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oH9EWw/1)

Comment: Lookaheads are supported in VBScript regex. Try `^type=dog[\s\S]*?^name=(\w+)(?:(?:(?!^type=)[\s\S])*?^color=(\w+))?` with `regex.Multiline = True`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dcQTe2/2).

Comment: Seems, you are absolutely right @WiktorStribiżew. By the way, I'm absolutely astonish with number of your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `regex.Multiline = True` and use the following regex:

```
^type=dog[\s\S]*?^name=(\w+)(?:(?:(?!^type=)[\s\S])*?^color=(\w+))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dcQTe2/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `type=dog` - a string
- `[\s\S]*?` - 0 or more chars as few as possible
- `^`  - start of a line
- `name=`  - a literal string
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: any one or more letters, digits or underscores
- `(?:(?:(?!^type=)[\s\S])*?^color=(\w+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `(?:(?!^type=)[\s\S])*?` - any char, 0 or more times, as few as possible, that does not start a `type=` substring at the start of a line
  - `^color=` - `color=` substring start of a line
  - `(\w+)` - Group 2: any one or more letters, digits or underscores